# New firebase json annotations

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using autovalue for my entities and annotated them to allow json parsing.

There are new annotations in the new sdk: `Exclude`, `IgnoreExtraProperties`, `ThrowOnExtraProperties` and `@PropertyName`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName. But PropertyName seems to be missing from the sdk..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We missed the `@PropertyName` annotation in this release of the Firebase SDK for Android, but it was included in a release shortly after.

See this answer for a way to use Jackson explicitly with any version of the Firebase SDK: [How to deserialise a subclass in Firebase using getValue(Subclass.class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547399/how-to-deserialise-a-subclass-in-firebase-using-getvaluesubclass-class/37548330#37548330)

Comment: Will i be fine if i stick to jackson's `@JsonProperty ` annotation till then?

Comment: Yes. Once we introduce the property I recommend you switch over, since it'll significantly reduce the size of your apk.

Comment: I included compile jackson-annotations:2.7.4 and jackson-databind:2.7.4, but it looks like firebase is ignoring both `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonSerialize` annotations.

Comment: You'll have to serialize it to a `Map` yourself using `new ObjectMapper().converValue(pojoValue, Map.class);` and then pass that map into `setValue()` or `updateChildren()`.

Comment: January 2020 and this issue is still not fixed! though the property name WAS included in the code of 21.3.1, it is buggy and simply does not work!

Comment: @LenaBru This was fixed years ago. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName

Comment: I spent some time on this this morning, with the latest version, it ignores properties which cannot be legal members. I.e property named "find-my-property" cannot be mapped to findMyProperty because it has "-" in it, and is simply ignored, on version 21.3.1

Comment: This was about the annotation simply not existing, while you seem to have problems making it work for your class. Please open a new question for that, as it seems like a new issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
BEFORE
@JsonIgnoreExtraProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class ChatMessage {
   public String name;
   public String message;
   @JsonIgnore
   public String ignoreThisField;
}

dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class)
AFTER
public class ChatMessage {
   public String name;
   public String message;
   @Exclude
   public String ignoreThisField;
}

dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class)
```

Refer to https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#update_your_java_model_objects_numbered