# Firebase: clean way for using enum fields in Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

My data on firebase uses many fields which have string type, but really are enum values (which I check in my validation rules). To download the data into my Android app, [following the guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), the field must be a basic `String`. I know I can work around this with a second (excluded) field which is an enum, and set this basing on the string value. A short example:

```
class UserData : BaseModel() {
    val email: String? = null
    val id: String = ""
    val created: Long = 0
    // ... more fields omitted for clarity
    @Exclude
    var weightUnitEnum: WeightUnit = WeightUnit.KG
    var weightUnit: String
        get() = weightUnitEnum.toString()
        set(value) { weightUnitEnum = WeightUnit.fromString(value) }
}

enum class WeightUnit(val str: String) {
    KG("kg"), LB("lb");
    override fun toString(): String = str
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun fromString(s: String): WeightUnit = WeightUnit.valueOf(s.toUpperCase())
    }
}
```

Now, while this works, it's not really clean:

- The `enum class` itself is (1) kinda long for an
  enum, (2) the insides are repeated for every enum. And I have more of them.
- It's not only enums, the `created` field above is really a timestamp,
  not a `Long`.
- Each model uses these enum fields a lot of times, which bloats the model classes with repeatable code...
- The helper field/functions are getting much worse/longer for fields with types such as `Map<SomeEnum, Timestamp>`...

So, is there any way to do this properly? Some library maybe? Or some way to write a magic "field wrapper" that would automatically convert strings to enums, or numbers to timestamps, and so on, but is still compatible with Firebase library for getting/setting data?

(Java solutions are welcome too :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the conversion between a property with your `enum` value and another property of `String` type is enough, this can be easily done in a flexible way using [Kotlin delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

To say it short, you can implement a delegate for `String` properties which performs the conversion and actually gets/sets the value of another property storing the `enum` values, and then delegate the `String` property to it.

One possible implementation would look like this:

```
class EnumStringDelegate<T : Enum<T>>(
        private val enumClass: Class<T>,
        private val otherProperty: KMutableProperty<T>,
        private val enumNameToString: (String) -> String,
        private val stringToEnumName: (String) -> String) {

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return enumNameToString(otherProperty.call(thisRef).toString())
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        val enumValue = java.lang.Enum.valueOf(enumClass, stringToEnumName(value))
        otherProperty.setter.call(thisRef, enumValue)
    }
}
```

**<sup>Note: This code requires you to add the Kotlin reflection API, [`kotlin-reflect`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect),  as a dependency to your project. With Gradle, use `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"`.</sup>**

This will be explained below, but first let me add a convenience method to avoid creating the instances directly:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> enumStringLowerCase(
    property: KMutableProperty<T>) = EnumStringDelegate(
    T::class.java,
    property,
    String::toLowerCase,
    String::toUpperCase)
```

And a usage example for your class:

```
// if you don't need the `str` anywhere else, the enum class can be shortened to this:
enum class WeightUnit { KG, LB } 

class UserData : BaseModel() {
    // ... more fields omitted for clarity
    @Exclude
    var weightUnitEnum: WeightUnit = WeightUnit.KG
    var weightUnit: String by enumStringLowerCase(UserData::weightUnitEnum)
}
```

Now, the explanation:

When you write `var weightUnit: String by enumStringLowerCase(UserData::weightUnitEnum)`, you delegate the `String` property to the constructed delegate object. This means that when the property is accessed, the delegate methods are called instead. And the delegate object, in turn, works with the `weightUnitEnum` property under the hood.

The convenience function I added saves you from the necessity of writing `UserData::class.java` at the property declaration site (using a [reified type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters)) and provides the conversion functions to `EnumStringDelegate` (you can create other functions with different conversions at any time, or even make a function that receives the conversion functions as lambdas).

Basically, this solution saves you from the boilerplate code that represents a property of `enum` type as a `String` property, given the conversion logic, and also allows you to get rid of the redundant code in your `enum`, if you don't use it anywhere else.

Using this technique, you can implement any other conversion between properties, like the *number to timestamp* you mentioned.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation :) I've implemented something based on your advices, but finally it seems that the delegated properties are skipped by firebase libraries when getting/saving objects from/to the database. Do you maybe have any idea how to work around this? Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737499/firebase-db-models-with-kotlin-delegated-properties

Comment: @quezak Try to use `@PropertyName`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work I don't have any experience with Firebase, but it looks like it just works only with fields by default.

Answer (score 5):

I am in similar situation & thus found your question, plus whole lot of other similar questions/answers.

Cant answer your question directly but this is what I ended up doing: I decided to change my app & not use enum data types at all - mainly because of the advice from Google dev portal which shows how bad the enum's are on app's performance. See the video below https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE