# firebase db: models with Kotlin delegated properties

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin objects to work with my Firebase Database models, as described [in the guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write). I have many fields that are stored as strings, but really are enums, so to be type-safe I have enum fields in the models, plus a string delegated property that returns the firebase stored value (as suggested in [a question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651507/firebase-clean-way-for-using-enum-fields-in-kotlin-java) some time ago). Now, these fields work if I get/set the string delegate in code, but firebase libs seem to skip them when converting to/from database's json format.

A simple example:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    @Exclude
    open var path: String? = null  // fails even if I delete this field!
}

class Weight() : BaseModel() {
    constructor(v: Double, u: WeightUnit) : this() {
        value = v
        unitEnum = u
    }

    var value: Double = 0.0
    @Exclude
    var unitEnum: WeightUnit = WeightUnit.KG
    var unit: String by EnumStringLowercaseConverter(WeightUnit::class.java).getDelegate(Weight::unitEnum)

}

[...]
val testWeight = Weight(7.0, "kg")
db.getReference("/valid/path/to/save/testWeight").setValue(testWeight)
            .addOnSuccessListener { r -> Log.d(LOG_TAG, "set successful") }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e(LOG_TAG, "set error", e) }
```

The `setValue` always gives a `Permission Denied` error, but works, if I delete `unitEnum` field and make `unit` a normal `String` property.

It's similar for reading: Firebase gives no errors when getting a Weight object, but the `weightUnit` field is never set to anything else than the default. But, if I manually do `weight.unit = "lb"`, the `unitEnum` field properly returns `WeightUnit.LB`.

I'm using firebase libs v10.0.1

Now, the questions:

- What can I do to make the delegated properties work correctly with firebase? I can try a different approach to the delegated enum fields, as long as the points from [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651507/firebase-clean-way-for-using-enum-fields-in-kotlin-java) are satisfied (readable, concise and type-safe code).
- is there any way to see how **exactly** do firebase libs convert objects to/from json? Or at least see the converted json? Maybe then I could tweak things myself. Unfortunately, everything firebase-related shows as `/* compiled code */` in AndroidStudio.

**UPDATE**: I could of course add a `toMap()` method to each model, where I would construct a map containing all the properties needed in firebase, but it would be tiresome to do this for every model, and it solves the saving issue only, the enum fields still wouldn't be set when getting.

The delegated props are also skipped when serializing with GSON. So maybe is there a generic way to make the delegated properties look like regular fields?

Comment: GSON doesn't allow serializing functions, and by extension getters/setters which delegates are. One possible solution is to make a unitEnum a delegate which on updates also update the unit string.

`var unitEnum: WeightUnit by EnumStringUpdate(WeightUnit::class.java).getDelegate(Weight::unit)`

Comment: `::class.java` is deprecated, use `.javaClass`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should work.

```
@get:Exclude @set:Exclude
var unitEnum: WeightUnit = WeightUnit.KG
var unit: String
    get() = unitEnum.name
    set(v) { unitEnum = WeightUnit.valueOf(v) }
```

Comment: This is the obvious solution, I know this would work, but take a look at the previous question I linked above, about why I don't want to do that :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651507/firebase-clean-way-for-using-enum-fields-in-kotlin-java

In short: (1) I have enum fields which don't convert directly as you posted, (2) I have lots of those fields and don't want to repeat code, (3) I have fields to convert that are more complicated than simple enum.

Comment: @quezak I would stick with `@StringDef` annotation, just hate enums (: Also, think about creating methods `toMap()` and `fromMap()` instead of serializing/deserializing using built-in firebase methods

Comment: yeah, I'm now working on a generic `toMap()` and `fromMap()` that will suit my case. The advantage is no doubled fields in model classes. The downside may be the whole model needs to be converted on read/write, not just the enum fields -- but for now my models are small enough that this shouldn't be an issue. (and firebase probably does some processing anyway, with similar compleixity)