# Android access Firebase with Keys with spaces in them

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This might be a dumb question but I couldn't find any examples on google's firebase site. If I have a key in the firebase database of `"First Name"` and then I call

```
FirstNameClass firstName = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirstNameClass.class);

FireNameClass{
    Private String FirstName;
    FirstName(){
    }
    FirstName(String firstName){
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

It'll return null because it's trying to map to FirstName instead of First Name with a space. Is there a different way to achieve this because all my values have spaces in them just by design and I am willing to do extra work to keep this design if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `@PropertyName`. Your model should look like this:

```
FireNameClass{

    @PropertyName("First Name")
    public String FirstName;
    ...
}
```

> Note: I haven't tried it. If it doesn't work, I think I know another way to do it and will update this answer

Hope this helps

Comment: You are amazing! It works perfectly. Is there other way a cleaner way or just different?

Comment: There is another way, by replacing your space with "_" or something and replace it back when you retrieve value from database. But I think above one is much more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This got me most of the way there, however I needed to modify where @PropertyName went. Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42635329/4151220