# Spaces in String value entered in Firebase DB giving unterminated String error android

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been manually entering data's into Firebase DB and if the string i entered contains spaces, i am getting 
`JsonExceptionorg.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character`

After searching through some Stackoverflow questions, i also added `String.valueOf(obj.getString("key"))`; to my coding. But it doesn't work for me.

How to add String with spaces in value field in Firebase. Any suggestions would greatly help my learning.

[My Firebase Db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx38C.png)

My code

```
   rootRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               String Jsondatas=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonobj=new JSONObject(Jsondatas);
                        JSONArray gkArray = jsonobj.getJSONArray("GK");
                        for(int i=0;i<gkArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject obj_gk = gkArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String quest = String.valueOf(obj_gk.getString("Question1"));
                            System.out.println("Questiofrom fb"+quest);
                            String opt_one = String.valueOf(obj_gk.getString("option1"));
                            String opt_two = String.valueOf(obj_gk.getString("option2"));
                            String opt_three = String.valueOf(obj_gk.getString("option3"));
                            String opt_four = String.valueOf(obj_gk.getString("option4"));
                            String ans= String.valueOf(obj_gk.getString("answer"));

                            question.add(quest);
                            Option1.add(opt_one);
                            Option2.add(opt_two);
                            Option3.add(opt_three);
                            Option4.add(opt_four);
                            CorrectAns.add(ans);
```

Comment: The value should be Quoted. Did you try this?

Comment: @anandwana But i am entering manually into firebase.

Comment: Should i enter as /"value"/ in firebase?

Comment: You are entering values directly in the console. Right? then it should be like this:- `key: "Value1 Value2"`

Comment: I am attaching my firebase screenshot with the question. At question key, value will be entered with spaces. Can you please take a look at it @anandwana

Comment: could you please provide the code where you got this error?

Comment: As we are working with the firebase, we don't require JSONObject to work. Writing the code below using which you can access your database.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012107/android-access-firebase-with-keys-with-spaces-in-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("GK");
     databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {  
              your_text_view.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Question1").getValue().toString());
                     ...
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

If you want a list, use [FirebaseRecyclerView](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) to get the list of all question and their options.

Answer (score 2):

I did Simply like,

In Firebase,

```
What-is-your-name(Replaced spaces with "-")
```

And after parsing json,

```
value.replaceAll("-"," ");
```