# Firebase Firestore: Is there an equivalent of @SerializedName?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore (from Firebase). For a reason that I don't understand a variable of one of my classes is not saved (in Firestore) with his correct name.

Here is an example class :

```
data class ExampleClass(
        val id: String,
        val foo: String,
        val bar: String,
        val isEnabled: Bool)
```

When I save this object in Firestore, I have no problem with `id`, `foo` or `bar`. However, `isEnabled` is saved as `enabled`. The `is` is removed without any reason that I know of.

Do one of you know if this is normal? I want to save the value as `isEnabled` and not as `enabled`.

Also, is it possible to specify a "name" to use in Firestore for each value? So I could force to save that value as "isEnabled". I have seen @PropertyName ([Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName)) but it does not seem to have the effect I expect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, and intuitive.  It's the way that JavaBean type objects are serialized.  According to the [JavaBeans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) section 8.3.2 boolean properties disregard the "is" on the method name for boolean getters:

> **Boolean properties**
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a
>   getter method to match the pattern:
>
> public boolean is();
>
> This "isPropertyName" method may be provided instead of a
>   "get" method, or it may be provided in addition to a
>   "get" method. In either case, if the is
>   method is present for a boolean property then we will use the
>   "is" method to read the property value. An example
>   boolean property might be:
>
> public boolean isMarsupial();
>
> public void setMarsupial(boolean m);

Having "is" prefixed on a boolean is kind of redundant, in my opinion.  If you know a property is a boolean, the implication is that it implicitly "is" or "isn't" the thing in its name.

But if you really *must* change the name, you can use the [@PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) annotation:

```
data class ExampleClass(
    val id: String,
    val foo: String,
    val bar: String,
    @PropertyName(value="isEnabled")
    val isEnabled: Bool
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug. Everything makes sense now.
However the @PropertyName does not work for me :/

Comment: Ok, I found the reason of that last problem there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work?rq=1