# Data output from the FireBase database

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to kotlin. And so I need help. Thank. I have a date class Users ().

```
data class Users(
var ID: String = "",
var Email: String = "")
```

Date class I fill through initUser

```
lateinit var AUTH: FirebaseAuth
lateinit var UID:String
lateinit var REF_DATABASE_ROOT: DatabaseReference
lateinit var USER:Users

const val NODE_USERS = "User"
const val CHILD_ID = "ID"
const val CHILD_EMAIL = "Email"


fun initFirebase() {
    AUTH = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    UID = AUTH.currentUser?.uid.toString()
    USER = Users()
}

fun initUser() {
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_USERS).child(UID)
        .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                USER = p0.getValue(Users::class.java) ?:Users()
            }
        })
}
```

But when I want to display the user's email from the database via text. I get the void

```
initFirebase()
initUser()
textViewMain.text = USER.Email.toString()
```

Here is new JSON:

```
{
  "User" : {
    "ZDLM84F7zYWobbhUBxsQfekrPvI3" : {
      "Email" : "evgeniy1900@gmail.com",
      "ID" : "ZDLM84F7zYWobbhUBxsQfekrPvI3"
    }
  }
}
```

But again I get nothing in text

### **UPDATE:**

Ok, I wrote it all over again. And now I have:
Data class User

```
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName

data class User (
    @PropertyName("id")
    var id: String = "",
    @PropertyName("email")
    var email: String = ""
)
```

initUser looks like that

```
lateinit var AUTH: FirebaseAuth
lateinit var UID:String
lateinit var REF_DATABASE_ROOT: DatabaseReference
lateinit var USER:User

const val NODE_USERS = "users"
const val CHILD_ID = "id"
const val CHILD_EMAIL = "email"

fun initFirebase() {
    AUTH = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    UID = AUTH.currentUser?.uid.toString()
    USER = User()
}
fun initUser() {
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_USERS).child(UID)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener{
          USER = it.getValue(User::class.java) ?:User()
        })
}
```

and also I decided to shorten the code using AppValueEventListener
here he is

```
class AppValueEventListener (val onSuccess:(DataSnapshot) -> Unit) :ValueEventListener{
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) { onSuccess(p0) }
}
```

and this is json

```
{
  "users" : {
    "ZDLM84F7zYWobbhUBxsQfekrPvI3" : {
      "email" : "evgeniy1900@gmail.com",
      "id" : "ZDLM84F7zYWobbhUBxsQfekrPvI3"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I added @PropertyName ("email"). But at the same time, I still do not get anything on the screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3sBQ.png)

### Update again:

I used a breakpoint in order to understand if I am getting something from the database or not. As you can see in the screenshots, there is a receipt, but there is no record in the User model. Help me please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the JSON at `/NODE_USERS/$UID` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: If you `console.log(UID)` right before `REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_USERS).child(UID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...` what does it print?

Comment: I/System.out: ZDLM84F7zYWobbhUBxsQfekrPvI3

Comment: The breakpoint in that last screenshot is in a place where `USER` is unlikely to have the correct value. Any code that needs data from the database should be *inside* the `onDataChange` that is called for that data. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519.

Comment: Thanks, it works. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Btw: please don't leave `onCancelled` empty, as you're hiding potential errors. At the very least it should be `override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) { throw error.toException(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON contains this property for a user:

```
"EMAIL" : "evgeniy1900@gmail.com",
```

Which you likely want to map to this in your code:

```
var Email: String = ""
```

But Firebase uses JavaBean naming conventions when mapping, which means that your JSON actually maps to a property in Kotlin as:

```
var eMAIL: String = ""
```

If you want to maintain both the name on JSON and in Kotlin, you can use a `PropertyName` annotation:

```
@PropertyName("EMAIL")
var Email: String = ""
```

Also see: [Firebase @PropertyName doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work) and probably others from [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=kotlin+firebase+propertyname).

Comment: Not work.
Even when the EMAIL base was written in the same way as in the data class Users. Nothing worked anyway.

Comment: My FireBase new JSON:
{
  "User" : {
    "ZDLM84F7zYWobbhUBxsQfekrPvI3" : {
      "Email" : "evgeniy1900@gmail.com",
      "ID" : "ZDLM84F7zYWobbhUBxsQfekrPvI3"
    }
  }
}
But again I get nothing in text

Comment: Even in your updated data class the `var Email: String = ""` maps to a database property `email`, which is not what you have in your JSON.