# Kotlin data class with Firebase getValue mapping

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `data class` in Kotlin and I have a property in the class named `isFoo`, note that it starts with `is`. Kotlin creates setters differently for fields that start with `is` as mentioned [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties) due to this I am receiving an error that looks something like this

`ClassMapper: No setter/field for isFoo found on class com.domain.appName.models.Settings`

How can I overcome this so fields that start with `is` in the data class are correctly set when using the `getValue` function of the Realtime Database's `DataSnapshot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `PropertyName` annotation on the field and/or accessor methods to control how it is serialized to and deserialized from the database.

Comment: Your answer along with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820755/4961540) solved the issue.